# Why can’t I access my PCs BIOS with a USB keyboard anymore?

Tags: bios, reset, usb-keyboard

I read some of the related posts on here but couldn't really find the solution.

I have a PS/2 port but my PS/2 keyboard doesn't work on it anymore. Maybe it's broken or something. So, I got a new keyboard, a USB Keyboard and it worked just fine. I could enter BIOS with no problem and even formatted and re-installed windows on my computer so many times.

But, a few days ago, I tried accessing my BIOS setup and it wouldn't let my keyboard work. I even checked it by trying to boot with a CD, but it wouldn't accept my keyboard press even though all the lights on the keyboard were on.

I tried resetting the BIOS by switching off and on the switch at the back of my CPU, but it doesn't work. I keep hearing those clicks when I boot my PC. I read somewhere about Click BIOS but couldn't find one compatible with Intel.

Comment: Does the USB keyboard work within windows ?

Comment: To reset the BIOS, you can remove the BIOS battery and wait for a few seconds and put it back in. Not sure if there will be a switch to do that

Comment: @slayernoah pretty big approach for this problem. I would definitely not reset the BIOS to defaults just because the keyboard is not working.

Comment: @slayernoah yes, it does

Comment: @LPChip i have to reinstall windows. So i need the keyboard to work so i can boot from dvd

Comment: @Ashfaaq Can you try this with all the USB ports that you have? Sometimes motherboards give priority to a specific port

Comment: @slayernoah i did.... and i also removed the battery and put it back again dan now my computer does not even power

Answer (score 0):

USB keyboards require a small time before they are properly initialized. Just because the backlid works doesn't mean the keyboard is ready to be used. Usually if the numlock can be turned on and off, you know the keyboard is ready to be used.

The BIOS will initialize all your USB hardware in order, and once your keyboard has been initialized it will start to work.

You should unplug all your USB devices and only plugin your USB keyboard, reboot the computer (2 times or more if necessary) until your keyboard is able to work and you can access the BIOS. If it keeps failing, plug it into a different USB port.

Answer (score 0):

In the 2000s I had a computer with a Ps2 socket and USB socket and in those years, they weren't really built for the USB keyboards to reliably work that early in the boot process to use it in the BIOS.

So maybe your computer was maybe super old..  eg you in 2015 with a computer that was maybe 12 years old...

This computer issue you had in 2015 was more of an early 2000s problem, and wouldn't be an issue now in 2023+.

Once they phased out Ps2 from common computers that was when the USB had been made more reliable for accessing the BIOS from.

And I use the term BIOS because it was in more recent years that we got told no it's not a BIOS it's a UEFI. And BIOS is now a mode that the UEFI can be put in, and the mode is called legacy.

If you wre in 2015 with that issue then i'd say you should either fiddle with the ps2, e.g. try a new ps2 keyboard.  Or get a new computer.   No doubt by now you have gotten a new computer particularly as from your comments it eventually seemed to be not even powering up.

Anyhow. For whatever reason your old question got bumped, so i've posted an answer.

Comment: Wow. I didn't even know I was logged in into that same account until I had to google some command lines and saw the notifications. It's really funny because I had been trying to remember the name of those old keyboards for a few days now and this pops up. 

Anyway, thanks for replying. I don't even remember what the issue really was. But I know the motherboard was the issue, can't remember what exactly though. It's dead now, of course. But back in 2015, I remember I just had to wait a few hours to turn it on again and it worked just fine.

Comment: @Ashfaaq for waiting a while,  may have been some overheating issue

Comment: that was one of the main problems. It had a faulty fan, though what was faulty about it, I don't know. One time I sneaked out on time to go buy a completely new one (AFTER i'd watched tutorials to check if it was really dead and waited a whole day) only go come back to it working just fine. That pc was already about 7 years old in 2015 and the shop built it with a motherboard that was already considered outdated even back in 2008. I was too young to even know back then. I'll probably try to salvage the hdds when I go back home but the rest is trash now anyway.